# Change range depending on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

The code below highlights cells that are left blank when button is clicked. I need `myCellRange` to be different depending if cell B19 has ‘Open’ or ‘Closed’.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

```
Sub AreYouSure()

Dim myCellRange As Range

'identify cell range you work with
Set myCellRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Range("B5:B21,B23:B26")

'check if number of non-empty cells in range is less than total number of cells in range.
'Depending on result, display message box indicating whether cell range contains any empty
'cell (True) or not (False)

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(myCellRange) < myCellRange.Count Then

    myCellRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Interior.ColorIndex = 3

    MsgBox "Please Enter Data In Red Cells And Then Update."

    Exit Sub

End If

Call UpdateRecords

End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Select Case` or `If...ElseIf...End If`.

Comment: What do you mean with "different". What are your options? Can you elaborate, because then we can help you even more specifically =)

Comment: If B19 = Open range(B5:B17,B20:B24) and if Closed then as it is in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're stuck on as you don't specify, you just need an `If` clause along these lines:

```
Sub AreYouSure()

Dim myCellRange As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input")
    If .Range("B19").Value = "Closed" Then  'assuming it's B19 on the same sheet ...
        Set myCellRange = .Range("B5:B21,B23:B26")
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(myCellRange) < myCellRange.Count Then
            myCellRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            MsgBox "Please Enter Data In Red Cells And Then Update."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    ElseIf .Range("B19").Value = "Open" Then
        'Set myCellRange = ...
        'whatever
    End If
End With

Call UpdateRecords

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that’s fine the trick. I’m still learning so cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub AreYouSure()

  Dim myCellRange As Range

'identify cell range you work with
If Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Input").Range("B19") = "Open" then
   Set myCellRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Range("B5:B17,B20:B24")   
Else
   Set myCellRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input").Range("B5:B21,B23:B26")
End If

'check if number of non-empty cells in range is less than total number of cells in range. Depending on result, display message box indicating whether cell range contains any empty cell (True) or not (False)
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(myCellRange) < myCellRange.Count Then

myCellRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Interior.ColorIndex = 3

    MsgBox "Please Enter Data In Red Cells And Then Update."

  Exit Sub

 End If

  Call UpdateRecords

 End Sub
```